# Detecting EOF / TCP teardown using Java sockets from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, http, sockets, tcp

I'm creating a Java socket in Javascript, sending an HTTP request and receiving a response correctly but I seem to be unable to detect an EOF or the server closing the socket at the end. What am I doing wrong? The problem is we never exit the outermost while loop - the server stops transmitting and (presumably) closes its end of the connection, yet receiver.read() never returns -1 and all the socket methods return state consistent with the socket still being connected.

```
    var s = new java.net.Socket("www.google.com",80);
    var sender = new java.io.PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    var receiver = s.getInputStream();
    sender.print("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    sender.flush();
    s.shutdownOutput();
    var response = '';
    var eof = 0;
    while( !eof && s.isConnected() && s.isBound() && !s.isClosed() && !s.isInputShutdown() )
    {  
       if( receiver.available() )
       {
        while( receiver.available() )
        {
         var i = receiver.read();
         if( i == -1 ) { eof = 1; }
         else { response += String.fromCharCode(i); }
        }
        // at this point response does contain the expected HTTP response
       }
    }

    // in case remote end closed the socket before we got a chance to read all the bytes from it        
    // ...but this is never reached!
    while( receiver.available() )
    { 
      response += String.fromCharCode(receiver.read());
    }

    alert( response );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, further research suggests there is no non-blocking way to discover whether the remote side has closed a socket. However, it is possible to achieve this using NIO channels:

```
    var s = new java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(new java.net.InetSocketAddress( "www.google.com",80) );
    //ew, but while we're prototyping...
    s.configureBlocking(true); 
    var sender = new java.io.PrintStream(s.socket().getOutputStream());
    sender.print("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    sender.flush();

    s.configureBlocking(false); // yayy!

    var response = '';
    var len = 0;
    var dbuf = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate( 1024 );
    while( len >= 0 )
    {    
         len = s.read( dbuf );
         dbuf.flip();
         while( dbuf.hasRemaining() )
         { 
           response += String.fromCharCode( dbuf.get() );
         }
         dbuf.clear();
    }

    alert( response );
```

Comment: You shouldn't proceed with the `flip()` &c unless `len` was positive. It's all just a waste of time. Better to put the `read()` into the `while` condition.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't the this:

```
      while( receiver.available() && !eof)
```

be better? in lieu of the first while( receiver.available()) ?

Comment: Seems a bit redundant - available() is defined as returning the number of bytes of data available to read without blocking, so would return 0 after EOF. Tried it anyway just in case; doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Or do you mean in place of the outermost while? Data being available to read without blocking is independent of whether the server has closed the socket - there could be pauses in transmission, and the OS could have buffered input data. So we must test both separately.

Comment: No, I meant the inner while, but your first comment is right: I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

When the end of the stream is reached, available() returns 0, so in your code, you never read the -1

Comment: Right. But read() will block until either EOF is reached or there is more data, and Javascript is single-threaded so we don't want to issue a read without knowing for certain we have data to read. And available() can return 0 during transmission, so we can't use that to test for EOF.

Comment: `available() == 0` means there is no data to be read without blocking, which can happen any time. It does *not* mean end of stream. Answer is incorrect.